# Script to pull hashes out of large text file

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed, awk

I am attempting to write a script that will pull out NTLM hashes from a text file that contains about 500,000 lines of data. Not all accounts contain hashes and I only need the ones that do contain hashes.

Here is a sample of what the data looks like:

> Mango Chango A (a):$NT$547e2494658ca345d3847c36cf1fsef8:::

There are thousands of other lines in the file, but that particular line is what I need taken out of the file. There are about 100 lines that apply to that and I do not want to manually go through the entire file searching for that.

Is there an easy script or something I can run in Linux to pull lines that follow that pattern out of the file?

Thank you!

Comment: doesn't `grep` do the job?

Comment: @ChangoMango, you should accept the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

`grep '\$NT\$'`*filename*

If there might be other occurrences of $NT$ outside the field you're looking for, you could be more specific - this will find only lines that have it in the second colon-delimited field:

`awk -F: '$2 ~ /\$NT\$/'`*filename*

Comment: Will this also pull the data before it? I would like the entire line which would include the username.

Comment: The parentheses aren't really necessary.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: good point, you could do without them in this case.  Edited.

Comment: It's not necessary to escape the leading `$` in your `grep`; since it's not at the end `grep` does not treat it specially.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on specificity:

```
grep -E ':\$NT\$[[:alnum:]]{32}:'
```

You could use range, if necessary:

```
grep -E ':\$NT\$[[:alnum:]]{30,34}:'
```

or be more general:

```
grep -E ':\$NT\$[[:alnum:]]+:'
```

`[:alnum:]` is a named class of characters which includes all the alphabetic characters, upper and lower, and all the numeric characters in your current locale.

Other character classes include `[:alpha:]`, `[:cntrl:]`, `[:digit:]`, `[:graph:]`, `[:lower:]`, `[:print:]`, `[:punct:]`, `[:space:]`, `[:upper:]`, and `[:xdigit:]`.

I would have used `[:xdigit:]`, but the has includes an "s".

Answer (score 0):

In Bash and many other shells:

```
grep ":$NT$" your_file.txt
```

Quotes will let $ pass into pattern unmolested.

Comment: No, they won't.   The above will expand `$NT`, and then look for whatever that expands to at the end of the line.  If you don't want to do that, you have to use single quotes, or put a backslash in front of the first dollar sign, and either way you have to put a backslash in front of the second dollar sign.

Comment: Will this also pull the data before it? I would like the entire line which would include the username.

Comment: > $ cat 123.txt
> Mango Chango A (a):$NT$547e2494658ca345d3847c36cf1fsef8:::
> 123
> 321
> NT
> $NT
> $ env NT=123 grep ":$NT$" 123.txt 
> Mango Chango A (a):$NT$547e2494658ca345d3847c36cf1fsef8:::
> Sorry, I can't figure out how to make line breaks in comments, so assume > blocquote ident as line break.

Comment: Will this pull only that line out? Will it also pull other usernames?

Comment: @ChangoMango, yes, this will output entire lines.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: The only way that will work is perhaps in Windows where double quotes are used instead of single ones and if you have `grep` aliased to `grep -F`. Otherwise, as Mark said, the apparent variable will be substituted and the second dollar sign would be considered as an end-of-line anchor. In your demonstration, setting `NT` has no affect on the current environment where the `$NT` variable is evaluated in the argument to `grep`. That evaluation is performed before `grep` is executed. The variable set by `env` is only visible to `grep` once it is executing.

Comment: So what your `grep` is doing, in effect, is saying "show me all lines that end with a colon".

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: great, now add some lines that don't contain $NT$ and try again.  They'll all show up.  Also, as Dennis said, setting NT via env has no effect on the command line containing the env.

Comment: Don't you see that there's plenty of lines without NT in cat? No, it is not Windows.